# Remove white spaces around the images

Tags: css, wordpress, image, widget

I am working on a website
http://weddingempires.com/category/planning/

There are images in the right side of the website i.e. in the right side bar. You can see that the images have white space around them. I want to remove that white space. I want the images to be fit into the space and no white space should be there. Please tell me that how can I do this. I think some CSS will do work. But I do not know which classes should be targeted. Please help me in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Chrome Dev tool by pressing the combination

> ctrl+shift+I

DevTools can help you edit pages on-the-fly and diagnose problems quickly. I've found that you have extra padding in the sidebar just remove that it will fix.
Here are the classes

> .sidebar-primary .widget

I hope it will work. I have tried using Devtool it works fine.

Comment: I add padding: 0px;
It removes the space but removes the space from all other elements as well and it is looking very ugly now. You can see it by yourself. What I want is to only remove the space around the image and not the rest of widgets.

Comment: If you just want to remove the padding around the image add another class to the section tag and set padding to 0px.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me how can I add class to the section.

Comment: While registering your sidebar, there are two parameters for add new tags and class which are before_widget and after_widget. Please take a look [at](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)